# error 9 the bootstrap could not be loaded. device connectivity component

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce, bootstrapping, smartphone

I am developing an application for Motorolla MC18 (handheld mobile computer) in Visual studio 2008 SP 1. While debugging the application I am getting an error "error 9 the bootstrap could not be loaded. device connectivity component".
I have installed supporting softwares like EMDK for .Net, Device center.
My computer uses Windows 7, 32 bit Operating system.

Any one please help me to solve this issue.

### What I have tried:

I have tried installing EMDK for C as I have read it from one of the suggestions made
here. https://developer.zebra.com/thread/29897

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the PSDK (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/mk3100-software-development-kit.html) on your machine. This is solved this issue for me.